# error when I use ArrayList in fxml

Tags: javafx-8

```
  <children>
   <fx:define>
       <ArrayList fx:id="buttons">
       <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
       <Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
       <Button fx:id="btn3" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
       <Button fx:id="btn6" layoutX="505.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
       <Button fx:id="btn4" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
       <Button fx:id="btn5" layoutX="436.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
       </ArrayList>
   </fx:define>
```

I get error in each button and I even can't open fxml in sceneBuilder. What is wrong with this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8I3X.png)

Full code of fxml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<?import java.util.ArrayList?>
<AnchorPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

   <children>
       <fx:define>
           <ArrayList fx:id="buttons">
           <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
           <Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
           <Button fx:id="btn3" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
           <Button fx:id="btn6" layoutX="505.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
           <Button fx:id="btn4" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
           <Button fx:id="btn5" layoutX="436.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
           </ArrayList>
       </fx:define>
   </children>



</AnchorPane>
```

I want to store all buttons in one array in controller

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to add children in a List, especially standard `ArrayList`. FX components use `ObservableList` to store children components.

I suggest you add your buttons to a group, like this:

```
    <AnchorPane>
        <Group fx:id="group">
            <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"/>
            <Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"/>
            <Button fx:id="btn3" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"/>
            <Button fx:id="btn6" layoutX="505.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"/>
            <Button fx:id="btn4" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"/>
            <Button fx:id="btn5" layoutX="436.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"/>
        </Group>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Your buttons will be visible in your app and you can do operations on group children almost like it was a standard list.